# MySQL Search Operators and "LIKE"

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm having a strange issue where using the % operator isn't grabbing the right database entries for my autocomplete bar.

Here is a sample of my database structure:

[image]

Here is what happens when I search the letter 'g' in my search bar. Note that I have the query echoed at the bottom of the div so you can see the correct thing is being searched:

[image]

Then here is what happens when I add an 'a' after the g. You would expect the entry to remain there, as the entry's name is "aattaagataca", and it contains a ga, flanked by some other characters.

[image]

On another note, the search of the letter 'g' didn't return the '5gooper' entry. Any ideas as to why this might be happening? I will post my sample code, but please don't making comments about sql security cause I'm just coding the raw stuff for now. Also don't redirect me to jQuery UI's autocomplete because I'm not looking to use that.

**PHP**

```
$searchquery = $_POST['searchquery'];
$searchquery2 =  "%$searchquery%";

$query = "SELECT id, name, author, date FROM data WHERE name LIKE '$searchquery2' ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 20";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<a href=\"preview.php?id=$row[id]\"><div class=\"searchResult\">";
    echo $row["name"];
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<b>Author: </b>";
    echo $row["author"];
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<b>Date: </b>";
    echo $row["date"];
    echo "</div></a>";
    echo "<hr>";
}

print_r ($row);
echo "$searchquery2";
```

**JS/jQUERY**

```
$('#sbar').keyup(function(){

    var query = $(this).val();

    $.ajax
        ({
    url: "autocomplete.php", 
    data: {searchquery: query},
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        $('#acd').html(data); //acd stands for auto complete div
                            }
        });     

});
```

Basically my query is just very inconsistent with what it returns. When I query my SQL database directly (through phpMyAdmin, it indeed returns the correct entries. For example, a query such as:

"SELECT * FROM data WHERE name LIKE '%g%' ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 20"

Returns both entries which contain 'g' (gooper and gataca).

*****EDIT*****

Here is the result of typing 'g' and doing print_r ($row);

[image]

Comment: Can you try printing the contents of `$row` after the line `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);`?

Comment: Absolutely. Here is the print_r ($row);

Array ( [0] => 7 [id] => 7 [1] => 5gooper [name] => 5gooper [2] => geldb_admin [author] => geldb_admin [3] => 2014-07-19 17:33:39 [date] => 2014-07-19 17:33:39 ). I added a preview to my original post for you to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply remove the following line 
"$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);" from your code and you should be fine. Your application has already retrieved the first record before entering the while-loop. That's why you only get a single record while searching for %g% and no record while searching for %ga%

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much. Something I probably never would have caught. Very simple fix for a confusing problem, but makes sense now!